# @media Query not responding in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, responsive

So I'm trying to get this page to be responsive.. It works in firefox, and in chromes inspect tool, but regularly resizing chromes browser doesn't yield any results.

```
input {height:40px;}
@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
#form {
    width:600px;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
}
form {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 4fr;
    grid-template-rows: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
}
```

}

```
@media screen and (max-width:599px) {
#form, label, input {
    width:100% !important;
}
```

}

```
<div id="form">
     <form>
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="pet_name" id="name"></input>

        <label>Name2: </label>
        <input type="text" name="pet_name" id="name2"></input>
</form>
```

I have tried making sure its updating and setting colors to different media queries to see when they kick in, it never goes blue in chrome except in responsive mode.

Answer (score 0):

Start with adding this meta inside your `<head></head>`, missing this tag could be an issue

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Checked my document, I have that in there as well.

Comment: @BrentCarter do you have any way to show [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: done! I'm trying to get the form to collapse into 100% width lines

Answer (score 0):

you will refresh css in browser then media query will work.

I had tested your code in locally.

Comment: to clarify you tested it in chrome right? it seems to work in other browsers and chrome inspect mode, but even after clearing cache its not responsive by adjusting the browser size